# What's the caption character limit on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I thought I read somewhere it was 50 characters, but I've spent 45 minutes googling and found the character limits for wall posts, advertising, etc., but not the official limit.

I'm about to add photo sharing to my android app, and I need to limit the size of the caption to whatever the maximum number of characters allowed.

What is this limit?

I'll be using a combination of this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

and this: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/

To add the code to my app.

Comment: Have you tested empirically?

Comment: I was just going to start writing the code and didn't want to post tons of photos on facebook to test and thought there might be different limits programmatically and through the facebook website.

Comment: There probably isn’t a hard limit, it will likely just be cut off at different points when displayed in different locations (such as newsfeed vs full view of the single photo.)